# Javascript Google Classroom API - Get course homework

Tags: javascript, api, google-classroom

Right now I have the google classroom API working fine to get the name and section for each course that I have. I want to get the homework in a list for each course. How can I do this?

I currently have:

```
// Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
  // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
  var CLIENT_ID = '<CLIENTID>';

  var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"];

  /**
   * Check if current user has authorized this application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Handle response from authorization server.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadClassroomApi();
    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
   *
   * @param {Event} event Button click event.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Load Classroom API client library.
   */
  function loadClassroomApi() {
    gapi.client.load('classroom', 'v1', listCourses);
  }

  /**
   * Print the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to. If
   * no courses are found an appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listCourses() {
    var request = gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({
      pageSize: 10
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var courses = resp.courses;

      if (courses.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
          var course = courses[i];
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.className = 'class="col-md-4"';
          div.innerHTML = '<div class="col-md-4"> \
          <div class="jumbotron">  \
          <h2>' + course.name + '</h2> \
          <p>' + course.section + '</p> \
          </div> \
          </div> \
          </div>';
          document.getElementById('output').appendChild(div);
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No courses found.');
      }

    });
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
```

Comment: Even if I could just get the homework?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the quickstart (https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js)?  What are you getting for an error or what doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I could not figure what to put where.

Comment: @Wade73 the courseWork section is not as clear. There is no actual code.

Comment: The examples that there are are only for Python

Comment: The python is only there to server the page, I used an npm package http-server to run the same code.  I am getting a 401/403 error when I run the page.  I used Chrome's dev tools to see the errors, I would suggest you take a look as well.  The problem may just be the project setup.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I just want to add functionality. The code examples on the API docs are for the python API.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm if the Javascript client of Google API already has the Classroom API functionalities (since its still in Beta), but you can try to call out

gapi.client.[classroom/classroom.courses].courseWork.list({..parameters..},function(){...callback...});

Or, call the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) directly in Javascript, without using the JS client.

Comment: OK, I will look at this